# BroadCasterReciever causing programme to crash on restart

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app crashes because of my broadcaster on restart of the android device.

I have the following broadcaster

```
<receiver android:name=".IntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have found the error to be the line

```
<data android:scheme="file" />
```

My guess is that on resume of the app it tries to look up the file data and It is now null Or that it is now in a different state to it was when it got powered down.

Can someone please help me find a solution. I need this to be in the maifest as this receiver needs to run even when the app is no the current focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be adding a try catch for the whole of the onRecieve method.